# Move wp-admin to a subdomain on separate server wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site, `foo.com`. For various reasons, mainly caching, I need to move the wp-admin area to a subdomain `admin.foo.com` which is hosted on a separate server.

What's the best way to approach this, would a straight .htaccess rewirte work? I've seen that you can set `WP_ADMIN_URL` in wp-config.php but how do you separate the site in such a way that the amin sits on a different server than the rest of the site.

Comment: Try InfiniteWP - and hide the "usual" WP Admin with a random Name

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of two different installation of wordpress but the database will be same. One for staging and another for live

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a way to separate the frontend and admin area of a Wordpress site onto two different servers. Wordpress is a web application. You get the whole thing as a package.

If you've seen something like this before, the site owner is doing one of two things:

1. They are running Wordpress on the admin site only, then using a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=static) or some other technique to generate static HTML snapshots of the pages that form the public website.
2. They are using a [staging site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/) plus live site type architecture. Many of the new WP-specific hosting services include a staging site and a simple synchronization option.